# How to express period from one moment in time to another?

Tags: time, formatting

I must to inform my user that he has a reservation from one moment in time to another (with different dates and hours). What is the best way to express it? I was thinking about:

> you have an reservation from 2018-03-20, 7:00, to 2018-03-22, 10:00

but I'm not sure this is the clearest way. Some ideas?

Comment: That's great if you want a machine to read it. Try something more human, like: "You have a reservation on Tuesday 20th of March from 7am to 10am" - remember that it's going to be a human who reads this and try to write it as you might say it.

Comment: @AndrewMartin That doesn't account for multiple dates.

Karol, I recommend separating the times and dates - based on the "principle of grouping", I think it makes sense to split up two different days. For example:

Your reservations is confirmed.

Reservation begins: March 20th at 7:00 PM.

Reservation ends: March 22nd at 10:00 PM.

Comment: @S.G.A. The best solution is to tailor the response for single days and multiple days - However, my point still stands: it needs to be readable by a human and the current solution presented by the questioner is not. For multiple dates, the human approach could be something like: "You have a reservation between 7am on Tuesday 20th of March and 10am on Thursday 22nd of March" - Use human language if you want humans to understand it

Comment: @AndrewMartin I think more language just gets in the way here. Suppose you were booking a conference space. Which option would you prefer to arrive in the confirmation email? 

https://imgur.com/a/WITy2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to make it more readable by simply using line breaks and other typographic tricks.

You have a reservation
**from** > Tuesday 20th of March, 7am 
**to** > Thursday 22nd of Mach, 10am

Hope it helps :)